# How do I return an associative array key as string?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that is set up as follows

```
var myArray = [
    {'10/3/2014': "some value"}, 
    {'10/4/2014': "some value"}, 
    {'10/5/2014': "some value"}];
```

This is a simple version of the data I need, and I am able to access the values in the array just as I would expect.

My Question: How can I use the key value as a string?
I would like to be able to use the date I am using as a key in other places for display purposes.

Edit for more specifics about question

I have json data as follows

Events: {10/3/2014: [{}],10/4/2014: [{},{}],10/5/2014: [{},{}]}

each date represents has an array with one or more event details (actual data is removed so you can get the idea without taking up more room). I iterate through the items and use them as I would expect but I would like to use the dates and do not know how to access them.

Comment: This is not associative array, this is array of objects.

Comment: The question isin't clear. You want to create a single lookup object where keys are the dates to quickly lookup values based on specific dates?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I use the key value as a string?"? Have you tried iterating through the array with a for loop that has a nested for in loop to iterate through the object properties? What is the end result that you are attempting to achieve?

Comment: OK, I want to have what I am trying to do is have date keys, and objects assosiated with the keys. I would like to be able to display the date keys, without having to store them some other way. I think that since I already have them as keys I should be able to access them as strings.

Comment: use a for-in just like you use to process the value, the loop index is the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Object.keys()

Example:

```
var myArray = [{ '10/3/2014': "some value"}, {'10/4/2014': "some value"}, {'10/5/2014': "some value"}];
Object.keys(myArray[0])[0]; // will return '10/3/2014'
Object.keys(myArray[1])[0]; // will return '10/4/2014'
Object.keys(myArray[2])[0]; // will return '10/5/2014'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just set it up as an object like:

```
var myVar = { '10/3/2014': "some value", '10/4/2014': "some value", '10/5/2014': "some value"};
```

Then you can call it like

```
alert(myVar['10/3/2014']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I you want to create an object map out of your array where they keys are the dates, here's one way of doing it:

```
var myArray = [
    {'10/3/2014': "some value"}, 
    {'10/4/2014': "some value"}, 
    {'10/5/2014': "some value"}
];

var valuesMap = myArray.reduce(function (map, obj) {
    var date = Object.keys(obj).pop();

    map[date ] = obj[date];

    return map;
}, {});

//{10/3/2014: "some value", 10/4/2014: "some value", 10/5/2014: "some value"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that with the help of an array : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/et1m795a/

```js
var myArray = [{
  '10/3/2014': "some value"
}, {
  '10/4/2014': "some value"
}, {
  '10/5/2014': "some value"
}];

var splashArray = new Array(); //the array with the key names
$.each(myArray, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value, function(key, value) {
    //console.log(key, value);
    splashArray.push(key);
  });
});
document.write(splashArray[0]) /*10/3/2014*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user3648646 is this what you want